# UIImageAsset fills up memory with downloaded UIImage

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uiimage, uiimageasset

I have a problem where I am creating UIImageAsset objects to store multiple sizes of images downloaded from an API, but the memory allocated to the UIImageAssets does not free up any more.

In my testing this **only happens with downloaded UIImages**, not with those from the xcassets catalog using UIImage(named:) initializer.

In this example I am just using a random cat image from the internet, but that does the trick too.

```
func createImageAsset() {
        var scale = 1
        var asset = UIImageAsset()
        
        for _ in 0...5 {
            var data = Data()
            do {
                try data = Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/21/94/3b/21943bb9849d304ef77850a9df2d3020.png")!)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            asset.register(UIImage(data: data)!, with: UITraitCollection(displayScale: CGFloat(scale)))
            scale += 1
        }
}
```

To clear up why I use UIImageAsset: I'm trying to replicate behavior of the xcassets catalog to let the UIImageView get an appropriately sized image from this asset. Suggestions of other solutions are appreciated, but I am primarily looking for solutions/explanations for this memory issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution here?